# jQuery: looking for certain image viewer plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for a special jQuery plugin for displaying big images inside a canvas container with fixed dimension. What I mean is eg. - the container has `900x300px` - the image inside of it has `3000x2000px` - it should display at 100% zoom and be draggable by mouse for viewing.
it would be nice if it has easing (for quick mouse-movement).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This plugin](http://www.viget.com/inspire/jquery-image-scroller-plugin/) may be of help.